# Visual Studio 2022 showing deleted temporary files in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I just reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition and now it's showing deleted temporary files in the Solution Explorer view. There is no corresponding file actually in the directory as shown in this image (NOTE: Visual Studio Solution Explorer is on the right, Windows Explorer view of the same directory is on the left.)

[image: Windows Explorer on the left, VS Solution Explorer on the right]

I can manually delete the file, but if I edit a file again, it shows up when I save it. I understand that VS is creating a temporary file, then deleting it when I save my edits, but why is it showing up in my Solution Explorer? It doesn't happen with VS 2019, which I also have installed. It also doesn't happen with VS 2022 Pro, which I use at work. Can't find a setting that explains it, so I'm kind of stumped. It's more of an annoyance than anything else, but it's a large annoyance (at least to me).

Comment: This started happening on my Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Version 17.9.2 as well. Very annoying.